# Using ERB in IronRuby engine

Tags: hosting, erb, ironruby

I would like to use IronRuby with the ERB system to parse .erb format files and get the output.

In ruby this would be like:

```
require "erb"
erbContent = "..."
return ERB.new(erbContent,0,"%<>").result
```

But this just doesnt work in my IronRuby project. I get an exception about the erb file being missing... so I guess this is a libraries issue. I then initiated my Ruby engine with the paths to my IronRuby directories, which then throws a different exception:

```
allocator undefined for System::String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but I was providing the string to the script as a local variable through a scope.
The local variable was a .NET CLR string, which is what caused the issue ([please see here](http://ironshay.com/post/ironruby-tip-ruby-string-and-clrstring.aspx)).

The solution for me was to convert the string passed to ERB.new to a Ruby string using to_s.

Here's an example (Ruby snippet):

```
require 'erb'

template = ERB.new(template_code.to_s)
template.result(binding)
```

The C# Part which invoked the above script:

```
var scriptEngine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
var templateCode = "my ERB template code goes here";
// Pass the template code to the Ruby script through a scope
var scope = _scriptEngine.CreateScope(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
                                                  { 
                                                    {"template_code", templateCode}
                                                  });

var result scriptEngine.Execute(_boostrapScript, scope).ToString();
```

In the above C# snippet, _bootstrapScript is a string which contains the Ruby snippet above.